# How do I Scroll the LinearLayout with the RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, scroll, fragment

How do I scroll the first LinearLayout?
The CardView is base on the RecyclerView.

The RecyclerView can scroll by default but the first LinearLayout cannot scroll..
I want both of them scroll together.

I had tried to set ScrollView from the Main LinearLayout but doesn't work..
//read (1.pic)

Read the pictures to the following:

1. [XML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnxBK.png)
2. [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n06YP.jpg)

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1.3"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:text="Hello"
               android:textSize="20dp"/>
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/HelloUserText"
               android:text="Name"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:padding="10dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Switch"
       android:id="@+id/SwtichBtn"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
       android:textColor="@color/white" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="5">

       <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
           android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/recipes_list">

           </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

       </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us give you a great answer, it would help us if you have a glance at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. It would be also useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you provide some of the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use RecyclerViewMergeAdapter. ["See here"](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter) It is a small lib (Apache license) which merges multiple View or Adapter instances into one adapter, which can be then set to RecyclerView.

So you will do something like:

```
RecyclerViewMergeAdapter mergeAdapter = new RecyclerViewMergeAdapter();

LinearLayout ll = getLinearLayoutView();
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(context);

mergeAdapter.addView(ll);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(myAdapter);

recyclerView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```